# Update tables with new data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I receive new tables with data in bigquery everyday.

One tables = one date.

For example: costdata_01012018, costdata02012018 and so on.

I have script that union them every day so I have a new tables with all data I need. For now I truncate the final table every day and it doesn't seem right.

Is there any way to union them without truncation?

I just need to add a new table to the final one

I tried to create 'from' instruction that dynamically finds new table but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT date, adcost
FROM CONCAT('[test-project-187411:dataset.CostData_', STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d"), ']')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use  a table name build by a concat ..

Comment: Instead of trying to use dynamic table names (=lots of issues), could you have that date as an extra key-field in the single "costdata" table?

Answer (score 1):

Two options to do this:

```
#standardsql
SELECT date, adcost
FROM `test-project-187411:dataset.CostData_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Legacy SQL

```
#legacysql
SELECT date, adcost
FROM TABLE_QUERY([test-project-187411:dataset], 'tableid = CONCAT("CostData_", STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d")')
```

Comment: With this you will get the desired results. To add the results to an existent table, set the existent table as destination_table and set write_disposition to WRITE_APPEND. Take a look into [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result)